# Exclude templates in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

If I put a file up in my theme folder named `foo.php`  that only contains `<h1>Foo</h2>`, WordPress will automatically pull in the `home.php` file.

Is there any function to prevent that and have it simply render the file `foo.php`.  I'll still want to be able to use the wordpress functions from that page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Foo
*/
?>

<h2>Foo</h2>
```

Saved (obviously) as 'foo.php'.

Then, when you publish a page, through the dashboard using the 'Foo' template, that template will be used.

Comment: I still have a hard time w/ comments acting like config files in wordpess.  Thank you.

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy to explain why TimS' solution works.